# Does row and column of 2D arrays start at 0?

Tags: c++, arrays

Does `int myarray[7][7]` not create a box with 8x8 locations of 0-7 rows and columns in C++?

When I run:

```
int board[7][7] = {0};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
    {       
        cout << board[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I get output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 146858616 1 0 0 146858832 1 1978920048
```

So the 8 columns seem to work, but not the 8 rows. 
If I change it to `int board[8][7]  = {0};` it works on mac CodeRunner IDE, but on linux Codeblocks I get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1503452472
```

Not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two dimensional arrays are not different to the one dimensional ones in this regard: Just as

```
int a[7];
```

can be indexed from 0 to 6,

```
int a2[7][7];
```

can be indexed from 0 to 6 in both dimensions, index 7 is out of bounds. In particular: `a2` has 7 columns and rows, not 8.

Comment: Ahh crap I'm brand new to C++ for some reason I thought `int a[7]' created an array from 0 to 7

Comment: @AustinMW Since you are new: I strongly recommend using `std::array` (or `boost::array` if you are pre-C++11) instead of raw arrays. It is quite a bit easier to use and has no drawbacks (that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

`int board[7][7];` will only allocate 7x7, not 8x8.  When it's allocated, you specify how many, but indexes start at 0 and run to the size - 1.

So based on your source, I would say you really want `int board[8][8]`.

Answer (score 1):

`int board[7][7] = {0};` creates a 7x7 array. You are going out of bounds in your loop. Change it to `int board[8][8] = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

```
int board[8][7]  = {0};
```

When you do as above, you created only 8 rows and 7 columns.

So your loop condition should be as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) 
    {
```

If you try as follows system will print garbage values from 8th columns

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Araay starts from zero means that it will have n-1 elements not n+1 elements
try

```
int a[8][8] = {}
i = 0
j = 0
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<8;j++)
{
a[i][j] = 0;
}
}
```